# How to use GPU while training a model?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, gpu

I am running a code to train a resnet model on a kaggle notebook. I have chosen the accelerator as GPU so I haven't made any mistakes there. I am training the model using the following code:

```
model.cuda()
for epoch in range(10):
  model.train(True)
  trainloss=0
  for x,y in trainloader:

    x,y=x.cuda(),y.cuda()

    yhat=model(x)
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss=criterion(yhat,y)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    trainloss+=loss.item()

  print('Epoch {}  Loss: {}'.format(epoch,(trainloss/len(trainloader.dataset))))
  model.eval()
  testcorrect=0
  with torch.no_grad():
    for test_x,test_y in testloader:
      test_x,test_y=test_x.cuda(),test_y.cuda()
      yhat=model(test_x)
      _,z=yhat.max(1)
      testcorrect+=(test_y==z).sum().item()

print('Model Accuracy: ',(testcorrect/len(testloader.dataset)))
```

Network Code:

```
model=torchvision.models.resnet18(pretrained=True)

num_ftrs=model.fc.in_features
model.fc=nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(num_ftrs,1000),
                        nn.ReLU(),
                        nn.Linear(1000,2)
)
```

If you see I have used the .cuda() function on both my model as well as the tensors(inside the training part as well as validation part). However the GPU usage shown for the kaggle notebook is 0% while my CPU usage is up to 99%. Am I missing any code which is required to train the model using the GPU?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be that your model doesn't give GPU enough work. Try to make your network more GPU-hungry, e.g. introduce some linear layer with a bunch of neurons, etc. to double check that in that case you see increased GPU usage. Also I noticed that the measurement is delayed by a bit, so maybe you give GPU some work which it can do in a fraction of a second and the GPU usage bar doesn't have a chance to go higher from 0%.

Maybe you could share the actual network you're using?

I can see the GPU usage going to 100% in Kaggle notebook with a toy example like this  (notice 2500 x 2500 linear layer here):

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import numpy as np

trainloader = [(torch.Tensor(np.random.randn(1000, 5)), torch.Tensor([1.0] * 1000))] * 1000

model = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(5, 2500), nn.Linear(2500, 1500), nn.Linear(1500, 1))
model.cuda()
optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.01, momentum=0.)
criterion = lambda x,y : ((x-y)**2).mean()

for epoch in range(10):
  for x,y in trainloader:
    x,y=x.cuda(),y.cuda()
    yhat=model(x)
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss=criterion(yhat,y)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
  print(epoch)
```

Comment: I have added the details of my network, it may not be much I will try to make my network more dense and get back to this answer.

Comment: I don't imagine your main goal is to make GPU usage as high as possible. But just to see if GPU is used at all or not you can change your `model.fc` override by introducing e.g. another linear 1000 x 1000 layer after initial one. By the way, what is the value of `num_ftrs`.

Comment: The value of num_ftrs is 512.

Comment: I think your advice worked! I changed the linear layer to have an output size of 2500 and added another Linear layer but still, sometimes the GPU usage is 0 and suddenly increases to 100% and then drops to 0 again but I guess its working finally. Any idea why it is dropping to 0?

Comment: I think this is just an artifact of how Kaggle displays the GPU usage (maybe they average the usage over the last 1-2 seconds, etc.)

Comment: Oh okay! Thank you!